# Does the polynomials span the subspace of $p_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There is a problem in my Linear algebra book, that I have some trouble with. I have looked around on the forum, but cant seem to get the hang of it, because of the difference in polynomials, the degree of the polynomials etc.

Hope there is a kind stranger that can give me a tip!

Let $p_3(R)$ be a real vector space of polynomials: $p=ax+bx^2+c$ s.t.  $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ of degree $2$ or less.
Let $S=\{p \in p_3(R):p(1)=0\}$.

Sow that $p_1=1-X^2$, $p_2=X-X^2$ is a spanning set of S.

Comment: Recognize that every polynomial can be written in the form $(x-1)q(x)+r$ per the quotient-remainder theorem and polynomial long division.  Recognize then that the set of polynomials who are degree 2 or less who satisfy $p(1)=0$ are precisely those polynomials of the form $(x-1)(a+bx)+0$.

Comment: For an alternate approach, recognize that both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are elements of $S$ who are not multiples of one another and that there exist polynomials who do *not* satisfy $p(1)=0$ so $S$ is not the entirety of the space of polynomials degree at most $2$.  It follows then that the space spanned by $p_1,p_2$ is dimension $2$ subspace of $S$ and $S$ is dimension strictly less than $3$, so $S$ must have been dimension $2$ exactly and is precisely the space spanned by $p_1,p_2$.

Comment: Why is S todimensional? How do you proof it. It makes sense but how do one show it?

Comment: Well, $S$ contains at a minimum $p_1$ and $p_2$, two linearly independent elements... so it contains the span of $p_1,p_2$ and so contains a subspace of dimension $2$ so $S$ must be dimension at least $2$.  It is not equal to the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$ and so is of dimension strictly less than $3$ since the only dimension $3$ subspace of the space of polynomials of degree at most $2$ is the space itself which $S$ is not.  It follows then that $2\leq \text{dim}(S)<3$ and so $\text{dim}(S)=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $p(x)\in S$, then $p(1)=0$, and therefore, since $\deg p(x)\leqslant2$, $p(x)$ can be written as $(x-1)(ax+b)$, for some real numbers $a$ and $b$. But then\begin{align}p(x)&=a(x-1)x+b(x-1)\\&=a(x^2-x)+b(x-1)\\&=a(x^2-x)+a(x-1)+(b-a)(x-1)\\&=a(x^2-x)+b(x-1).\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! So because of this we can write any second degree polynomial, where $p(1)=0$  as a linear combination of $p_1,p_2$ for some $a,b∈R$ ?

Comment: No. We can write every element of $S$ as a linear combination of $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$.